# How to split a String array at every nth word?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm stumped on a (probably very simple) idea. I am reading in a text file with a BufferedReader, and splitting the string at whitespaces. I need to create a new string array and group the new elements in words of 3s from the previous array e.g. `{The, quick, brown, fox, jumped, over, the, lazy, cat}` ⇒ `{The quick brown, fox jumped over, the lazy cat}`.

So far I have come up with a very inefficient attempt that iterates over the array and concatenates elements and whitespaces to a new string array. It also leaves nulls in the new array because I am incrementing by `i+3` each time.

```java
String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String words[] = line.split(" ");
    String[] result = new String[words.length - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < words.length - 3; i += 3) {
        result[i] = words[i] + " " + words[i + 1] + " " + words[i + 2];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
}
```

An example of the output:

```
a Goose who null null was taking a null null walk by the null null side of the null null "Good heavens!" cried null null the Goose.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your friends are:

1. [`Math#ceil`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#ceil-double-)
2. [`String#join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)
3. [`Arrays#copyOfRange`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange-T:A-int-int-)
4. [`Integer#min`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#min-int-int-)

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int SIZE = 3;
        String[] arr = { "The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumped", "over", "the", "lazy", "cat", "Hello" };
        String[] result = new String[(int) Math.ceil((double) arr.length / SIZE)];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < arr.length; i += SIZE, j++) {
            result[j] = String.join(" ", Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i, Integer.min(arr.length, i + SIZE)));
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[The quick brown, fox jumped over, the lazy cat, Hello]
```

### How it works

`Arrays.copyOfRange` copies `arr` from the index, `i` to the index, `Integer.min(arr.length, i + SIZE) - 1` where `Integer.min(arr.length, i + SIZE)` returns the minimum of `arr.length` and `i + SIZE`. This is required for the last copy for which `i + SIZE` may go beyond `arr.length` causing `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Given below is an illustration for `10` elements in `arr` and `SIZE = 3`:

When i = 0, `Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, Integer.min(10, 0 + 3))` => `Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 0, 3)` which will return the subarray out of `arr` from the index, `0` to the index, `2`.

---

When i = 3, `Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 3, Integer.min(10, 3 + 3))` => `Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 3, 6)` which will return the subarray out of `arr` from the index, `3` to the index, `5`.

---

When i = 6, `Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 6, Integer.min(10, 6 + 3))` => `Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 6, 9)` which will return the subarray out of `arr` from the index, `6` to the index, `8`.

---

When i = 9, `Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 9, Integer.min(10, 9 + 3))` => `Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, 9, 10)` which will return the subarray out of `arr` from the index, `9` to the index, `9`.

---

Comment: Hi Arvind, thank you for you response the solution you provided worked perfectly. I understand the logic to some extent but as I am new to programming I would really appreciate a bit of further clarification on the Arrays.copyOfRange method logic. I understand it is returning a copy of arr and assigning it to the  result array based on a min and final index range. But I am a bit confused on particularly the max index - Integer.min(arr.length, i + SIZE)

Comment: You are most welcome. I've added an illustration for you. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method:

```java
public String[] splitArray(String[] array, int splitByNumOfItems) {
    String[] newArr = new String[array.length / splitByNumOfItems];
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    int newArrPos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if ((i + 1) % splitByNumOfItems == 0) {
            str.append(array[i]);
            newArr[newArrPos] = str.toString();
            str.setLength(0);
            newArrPos++;
        } else {
            str.append(array[i]);
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

**Test Run**

```java
String[] before = {
        "The", "quick", "brown",
        "fox", "jumped", "over",
        "the", "lazy", "cat"};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitArray(before, 3)));
```

Prints:

```
[Thequickbrown, foxjumpedover, thelazycat]
```

**Explanation**

We can create a new array called `newArr` which will house the items of the original array called `array`.

We can loop through the items of `array`, and everytime it loops, we check whether the current position is divisible by `splitByNumOfItems`. If it is, we can set it to the corresponding position in `newArr`, as determined by `newArrPos`.

Answer (score 1):

Test this code:

```java
String line = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String words[] = line.split(" ");
    String[] result = new String[((words.length - 1) / 3) + (((words.length - 1) % 3) > 0 ? 1 : 0)];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        result[i] = words[j] + (words.length > j + 1 ? (" " + words[j + 1]) : "") + (words.length > j + 2 ? (" " + words[j + 2]) : "");
        j += 3;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(result[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, much appreciated. It has really helped clarify the logic with preventing the out of bounds, & using the additional variable.

Comment: You're welcome. It's not necessarily the best way to do it but I figured you need to stay in this approach just for learning as you said you were new to JAVA or there is a shorter way.

Comment: Agreed! Efficiency will come with time, but I am happy for now to just learn the logic of these kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`iterate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#iterate(int,java.util.function.IntPredicate,java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)) over the indices of this array with a step of three elements and at each step use [`Arrays.stream(T[],int,int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(T%5B%5D,int,int)) method to get range of elements from the current one to the next third element and concatenate them using [`joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)) with whitespace delimiter:

```java
String[] arr = {
        "The", "quick", "brown",
        "fox", "jumped", "over",
        "the", "lazy", "cat"};
```

```java
String[] arr2 = IntStream
        // every third element 0, 3, 6
        .iterate(0, i -> i < arr.length, i -> i + 3)
        // stream over the elements of the array with
        // a range from the current element to the next
        // third element, or the end of the array
        .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(arr, i, Math.min(i + 3, arr.length))
                // join elements with whitespace delimiter
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
        // return an array
        .toArray(String[]::new);
```

```java
// output line by line
Arrays.stream(arr2).forEach(System.out::println);
// The quick brown
// fox jumped over
// the lazy cat
```